# Defining and using constants inside Rspec's hooks

Tags: ruby, rspec, constants

I am kinda of new to Rspec and I am writing some test examples when a question came up.

First, I was using global variables to define three constant values I was going to use in a lot of tests. For example:

```
$message = 'this is a test'
```

However, I notice that this global was being carried over to other test files and causing issues. Ok... decided then to avoid the globals as this can cause a lot of pain in the future in case my test file number grows.

I then went for the let() block. Example:

```
let(:message) { 'this is a test' }
```

Now the problem was that this variable could not be used inside before and after hooks. Ok...

My last try was using constants inside the contexts/describes, like this:

```
self::MESSAGE =  'this is a test'
```

However, just like let's this cannot be used inside the hooks as they are not either classes or modules.

So, I am stuck ...

How do you guys deal with that? Will I need to create instance variables for that? Is that any other alternative I can use?

Thank you very much.

Comment: To be clear, values `let` values *can* be used in `before(:each)` and `after(:each)` blocks. They can't be used in `before(:all)` blocks. In general I think `before(:all)` blocks are a code smell, so refactoring your tests to use only `before(:each)` blocks may solve this issue.

Comment: Ok, yeah ... I am still grasping the best approach for my tests so I will take your advice in consideration! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You have one other option for defining data -- instance variables.

```
before do
  @data = [ {one: 1, two: 2},
            {one: 2, two: 3} ]
end
```

You can use @data in all the tests within the scope of the `before`.  This is pretty much the same as `let` for the purposes of just setting up static data, but it might be a better fit for you -- without seeing your code it's hard to say.

Comment: Cool, I thought of instance variables but not the way you put it here. This looks good indeed, I'll give it a shot definitely. Thanks! Just one question though, this before block there is for :each or :all?